# D3 time label customization into two lines

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 line graph with time labels on my x-axis in the form "Jul 24 14:00" and integers on my y-axis.
I was wondering if it is possible to customize the time labels of x-axis in two horizontal labels eg "Jul 24" in the first line and "14:00" in the second line.
I dont want to rotate them because it [doesn't look nice](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/0e276dc70bb9184727ee47d6dd06e915)

I have found [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3netxer/10a28b7aee406f4e7fce) example which is similar to what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add .axis-second .tick line {display: none;}  to my CSS for the second x-axis in order to remove the ticks. Now it looks perfect!